# How to get live Speech to Text using AWS Transcribe in android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-transcribe

I want to convert the Live speech of the user to text using AWS Transcribe API. For some reason, there is no proper documentation on how it is to be done in android.
This is the link to do it in an inefficient manner
[Speech to text by AWS service using Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47586265/speech-to-text-by-aws-service-using-java-api)
In this link, the solution is to get the audio file from the user, store it to the S3, and then convert it using transcribe and wait for it to get complete till around few minutes and store it back to the S3.

I want to do it without storing file to S3, converting it, again store the output file to S3. How can I do it ?

Comment: From what I've read [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/how-it-works.html) it looks like that's the only way Amazon Web Services is set up to handle voice to text. You may want to look into something google has like Cloud Speech-to-Text API

Comment: Hey @chinnc , thanks for the link. And regarding using some other service, I actually want to use the Transcribe Medical of the AWS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Transcribe streaming to transcribe live speech, the service supports websocket: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/websocket-med.html